# Difference Between Class Library & ASP.NETvNext Class Library?

Tags: c#, class-library, asp.net-core

What are the differences between `Class Library` & `ASP.NETvNext Class Library` projects? From project creation in `VS 14 CTP`, it seems like class library hasn't changed at all whereas 'ASP.NETvNext Class Library' includes the new project.json file. However, it's not clear whether it has any benefits related to ASP.NETvNext or not?

This [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1025) says that compilation is dynamic for this ASP.NETvNext library project. Is there any other differences between the two of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another advantage are that the vNext projects output nuget-packages on build, while pre-vNext class libraries only output DLLs. If you specify multiple target frameworks in your project.json file the nuget-package from building will contain a DLL built for all of these target frameworks.

As an example here is a project.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-*",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0.0",
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": {},
        "aspnetcore50": {}
    }
}
```

If you run the "kpm build" command from the class libraries project folder it will output a nuget-package containing the following files.

```
lib/aspnetcore50/ProjectName.dll
lib/aspnetcore50/ProjectName.xml
lib/net45/ProjectName.dll
lib/net45/ProjectName.xml
```

When you reference this class library from other projects it will use the correct DLL depending on the target framework it requires.

Comment: Does it has anything to do with ASP.NET? I mean why it is named as ASP.NET vNext Class library (& available under web category in VS 14 as these benefits are available for other project types as well?

Comment: Currently only the ASP.NET vNext projects use the new project structure so no it is not a benefit available to other project types. It is called ASP.NET vNext Class Library because only ASP.NET projects can use them currently (without jumping through some hoops). There is a uservoice to support project.json for all project types over here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5987678-support-project-json-global-json-for-all-project-t. Go vote it up. :)